# How do I free up memory allocated implicitly in an array?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

For dynamic memory allocation in C, you have deallocate (or free) the reserved memory before you can execute and compile your program. For example:

```
....
... = malloc(...)
...
free(...)
return 0;
```

But how does it work if I don't use dynamic memory allocation. For example, if I reserve 40000000 bytes of space using `int array [10000000]`, how can I free up the memory later on in the program when I don't need it?

Comment: If allocated as a function's local array, it is automatically freed when you return from the function. Otherwise, you can't.

Comment: @WeatherVane, not exactly.  It is not `free` d because no heap space was ever allocated for it.  Its memory is on the stack, which `free` does not manage.  It would be more accurate to say that its memory is automatically "deallocated".

Comment: That is why I had edited the comment, to not say `free`d.

Comment: Okay so the memory is only freed when you return. But is there no way for the memory to be deallocated when you don't need it anymore, i.e. after you are done using it for its intended purpose?

Comment: @SkiMask Yes. You can define it inside a limited scope and it will be released when that scope ends. You can also just use dynamic memory allocation if you need more control over the object's lifetime.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz it's a moot point whether the stack memory will actually be available (as opposed to accessible) out of that scope, though. On return from a function, it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to allocate memory in C.

- *Automatic storage duration* (a.k.a. local variables) - allocated automatically when a block is entered (a function, `if` statement, loop, or whatever), and deallocated when the block is exited.
- *Static storage duration* (a.k.a. global variables and `static` local variables) - allocated automatically at the beginning of the program, and deallocated automatically at the end.
- *Dynamic storage duration* (a.k.a. the heap) - allocated with `malloc` and deallocated with `free`.

By the way, you *don't* have to deallocate everything before exiting the program. The operating system will deallocate all memory belonging to your program when it exits. (Otherwise you'd have to restart your computer a lot more often)

Answer (score 1):

There's a reason if it is called *dynamic* memory: it can be dynamically allocated/deallocated whenever you need it.

And there's a reason also if the opposite of dynamic memory is something... that's not dynamic: a static array like the one you mentioned cannot be deallocated.

What you need is the concept of **lifetime** of a variable:

- If `int array [10000000]` is a global variable, it's lifetime is the whole life of the program
- If `int array [10000000]` is within a block enclosed by curly braces `{ }`, it is stored in the stack and it's life ends as soon as the execution exits the block
- If within a block the variable is declared with `static` keyword (`static int array [10000000];`) its lifetime is the whole program life as well though its *scope* is limited to the block

Answer (score 1):

> For dynamic memory allocation in C, you have deallocate (or free) the reserved memory before you can execute and compile your program.

That's...confused.  Dynamic memory only exists *at runtime* - it has nothing to do with compiling or executing the program.  You `free` memory when you don't need it anymore *in the running program*.

As for things *not* allocated using `*alloc`...

If you define `int array[10000000];` within the body of a function and *without* the `static` keyword, then `array` has *automatic storage duration*; the memory for it is reserved when you enter the function and released when you exit<sup>1, 2</sup>.  If you define the array at file scope, outside the body of any function, or if you declare it with the `static` keyword, then `array` has *static storage duration* and memory will be reserved for it when the program starts and released when the program exits.

---

1. *Officially* speaking, memory is only guaranteed to be reserved when you enter that variable's *enclosing scope* - that is, if you define the array in the body of a `for` loop, then the memory is only guaranteed to be available for the duration of that loop.  However, as a practical matter, most compilers will allocate space for all locals at function entry and release it on function exit.

   Note that an array *that* large will probably cause a runtime error when you run the program - storage for local variables in an individual function is relatively limited.