# Creating a linked list without malloc in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to create a linked list without dynamic allocation and fill it with number from 0-8 and then
print them, but everytime I try it gives me random values.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct listNode
{
    int value;
    struct listNode *next;
};

int main()
{
    struct listNode list;
    struct listNode *head = &list;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        list.value = i;
        struct listNode new;
        list.next = &new;
        list = *(list.next);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        printf("%d, ", (*head).value);
        head = (*head).next;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It looks like it should be working but it doesn't, what am I missing?

Comment: `new` is going out of scope each iteration of your `for` and being destroyed.  Why are you trying to avoid `malloc`?

Comment: One way to avoid `malloc` when the number of nodes is known, is to work with nodes in a static array.

Comment: `list = *(list.next);` This overwrites your node with the content of the uninitialized new node. Any value you write to `value` is lost afterwards. Even if you want to avoid `malloc` you need to get some memory somewhere. Local variables are not suitable for that.

Comment: @StephenNewell because I didn't understand why we need it, now I do thank you.

Comment: *"I'm trying to create a linked list without dynamic allocation"* - because ?? I mean, I suppose you can do it with a fixed array of nodes whose `next` pointers you jockey into position, but if you were going that route you'd be just as well off using a 'next' *index* (not uncommon for symbol tables, fwiw, but still.).

Comment: @WeatherVane That's a good point! However, the array needn't be static, it just needs to persist at least as long as it is used.

Comment: @CiaPan Pretty sure the word "static" in that comment was not meant to be the literal `static` keyword. ["static" can also be used as the opposite of "dynamic"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64901332/3386109).

Comment: @user3386109 That's imprecise - 'static' is not opposed to 'dynamic'. They are not negations of one another, but rather they are two of three disjoint categories, and the third one is _automatic_. Those are local non-static variables. One could also classify variables into static and dynamic only, while dynamic ones would be further split into automatic and controlled (explicitly allocated with `malloc` family) - but this approach is much less common.

Comment: @CiaPan Perhaps, we can replace "static" with "global scope"  and move on?

Comment: @CraigEstey Alas, nope. Those are two unrelated notions. Consider `int getNextInt() { static int n; return ++n; }` The variable is static (it exists and keeps its value through the whole run time of the process) but obviously _not_ in a global scope (it is accessble only locally, within this one function).

Comment: @CiaPan You don't seem to understand that there are two different meanings of the word "static". In the **C** language, "static" refers to the `static` keyword. [In the **English** language, "static" is the opposite of "dynamic"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gq2Rv.png).

Comment: @CiaPan it doesn't matter whether the array is automatic or `static` here. The point is that neither use `malloc`. I could have complicated the issue by saying that I sometimes do use a dynamically allocated array when there is a large amount of node linking and reusing. In that case WhozCraig's comment is good: use the index to link, not the address, and then the array can be reallocated to obtain another chunk of nodes. Instead of `free` for an unlinked node, it goes into a linked list of available nodes, and when a node is needed, that takes priority over the next array element.

Comment: @WeatherVane That's exactly what I said: it doesn't matter if the array is static, _it just needs to persist at least as long as it is used_. EOT.

Comment: @CiaPan any variable you access must be in scope. It's not a special requirement here. I don't get why you won't let this go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allocate nodes without `malloc`, there is also a possibility to use the stack for this purpose. This is only interesting as a little exercise, but would be a bad idea in real code.

The idea is that whenever a new node must be allocated, you make a recursive call, and then continue the rest of the program's logic there without returning from that recursive call. Only when the program can exit, you would unwind out of recursion. This is not very handy to work with, leads to waste of memory, as not only the allocated nodes are on that stack, but also some other data that has no more use. Moreover, there is no reuse of space whenever a node is deleted from the list unless you also maintain a free list.

So again, this is not best practice, and one should really use the heap for such dynamic allocation. I hope this disclaimer was strong enough to still allow me to post this piece of code that implements this idea:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct listNode
{
    int value;
    struct listNode *next;
};

void printList(struct listNode *head) {
    while (head != NULL) {
        printf("%d -> ", head->value);
        head = head->next;
    }
    printf("NULL\n");
}

void deleteFromList(struct listNode **headPtr, struct listNode **tailPtr, int value) {
    while (*headPtr != NULL && (*headPtr)->value == value) {
        *headPtr = (*headPtr)->next;
    }
    if (*headPtr == NULL) {
        *tailPtr = NULL;
        return;
    }
    struct listNode *current = *headPtr;
    while (current->next != NULL) {
        if (current->next->value == value) {
            current->next = current->next->next;
        } else {
            current = current->next;
        }
    }
    *tailPtr = current;
}

void appendToList(struct listNode **headPtr, struct listNode **tailPtr, struct listNode *new) {
    new->next = NULL;
    if (*tailPtr != NULL) {
        (*tailPtr)->next = new;
    } else {
        *headPtr = new;
    }
    *tailPtr = new;
}

// This is the main program's logic, but it gets called recursively whenever a node
//   is inserted into the list:
void menu(struct listNode *head, struct listNode *tail) {
    struct listNode new;
    char choice;
    while (1) {
        printf("[i]nsert, [d]elete, [p]rint, [e]xit: ");
        scanf(" %c", &choice);
        switch(choice) {
            case 'p':
                printList(head);
                break;
            case 'i':
                printf("insert value: ");
                scanf(" %d", &new.value);
                appendToList(&head, &tail, &new);
                menu(head, tail); // Recursion
                return;
            case 'd':
                printf("delete value: ");
                scanf(" %d", &new.value);
                deleteFromList(&head, &tail, new.value); 
                break;
            case 'e':
                return;
        } 
    }
}
    
int main()
{
    menu(NULL, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```